# upload photo from memory smartphone to facebook

Tags: android, facebook

im new in programing android and im having trouble to upload a photo from sd card to facebook. My goal is that the user take a picture with a button "camera" on the app and then he can post that picture that is saved in the sd card on facebook by pressing the button "upload"

I followed this tutorial on FB site, which gives an example of publishing a picture from a web URL: postParams.putString("picture", "https:// image URL");

here is my code:
Camera button:

```
 botaoCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(missao_selecionada.this);
            builder.setTitle("Tem a certeza que quer tirar foto?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    //Intent abrirCamera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

                }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {

                    }
                    });

            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();



        };

});
```

Facebook post method:

```
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "GoodSam aPP");
    params.putString("caption", "GoodSam test");
    params.putString("description", "Lima");



    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params,  new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial you can find on [Facebook's developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-using-the-object-api/) might help you. Mind you: this example is a bit more oriented to sharing "stories" on Facebook, and you'll have to have a Facebook developer account, but still it might help...

Alternatively, download the Facebook SDK [here](https://developers.facebook.com/), you'll find some samples there that might help you with your task.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you're using is the feed dialog, which doesn't support photo uploads, it only takes an URL for the "picture" parameter, and will not allow you to upload a photo.

You need to upload photos with either the Graph API, or Open Graph.

See the Hello Facebook sample that ships with the SDK for an example on how to upload photos with the Graph API.